# Conservation Of Mechanical Energy

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, energy, energy-conservation, work

I just observed that ,
                      ***Mechanical Energy(E) = Potential Energy(U) + Kinetic Energy(K)***
Now ,
from simple algebra,
**E-U=K**
Also we know that Kinetic Energy **K** is always positive.
I wanted to know what will happen if **E**.
Will such a system exist or what will happen to the particle in such system?

Comment: read your question again :)

Comment: You are essentially asking "what will happen if everything remains the same?".  Those two equations are equivalent, regardless of signs.  If K is positive, that means E is greater than U, which it would have to be anyways.  E-U = K is the *exact same* as E = U + K

Answer (score 2):

The kinetic energy of a system can go down as the potential energy goes up.
So here the change in the kinetic energy is negative.

Think of a ball being thrown up in the air.

Comment: This had nothing to do with rates of change as far as I know.  It was instantaneous values.  The question was asking why it was still equal when rearranged, which is an odd question.